# TeamCity + Protractor doesn't really execute

Tags: protractor, teamcity

If i run tests locally with following test setup everything runs fine. However when i run tests on teamcity server, protractor tests get through in less than second and all them pass. It seems no promises will ever resolved, basically tests simply dont do anything. However if i add non asynchronous assert

```
except(1).toBe(2);
```

It fails and errors are reported correctly.

Test.ps1:

```
[CmdLetBinding()]
Param()

$env:path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\"

Push-Location $PSScriptRoot\..\

"Starting azure table storage emulator."
if (AzureStorageEmulator.exe status | select-string "IsRunning: False") {
    AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
}

"Clearing existing data from storage."
AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear all

"Running server side tests."
dnx test

"Protractor"
Get-Process -Name *chrome* | Stop-Process
$handle = Start-Process -FilePath "dnx" -ArgumentList "web-e2e" -PassThru

try {
    $results = gulp protractor
    $results

    if($results | select-string "error code") {
        throw "Protractor test failed."
    }
}
finally {
    try {
        $handle.Kill()
    } catch {}
    Get-Process -Name *chrome* | Stop-Process
}
Pop-Location
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('protractor', (cb) => {
    child_process.exec(`node ${__dirname}\\node_modules\\protractor\\lib\\cli.js .\\protractor\\protractor.conf.js --directConnect`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
    });
});
```

protractor.conf:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['**/*.spec.js'],
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/'
};
```

Team city log:

```
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] Using ChromeDriver directly...
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] Started
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] ...................
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] 
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] 
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] 19 specs, 0 failures
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] Finished in 0.82 seconds
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[20:15:15][Step 2/2] [launcher] chrome #1 passed
```

I tested when i explicitly break asynchronous except (for example change element id as nonsense). It fails locally, on TC it still passes.

I am slightly stuck here, it may be that --direct-connect causes issues behind, but it also makes setup simpler.

Comment: Probably this [guideline](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Common+Problems#CommonProblems-BuildfailsorbehavesdifferentlyinTeamCitybutnotlocally) could help to investigate the why the build fails in TeamCity.